# How to unmarshall a JSON that represents an Array of different type of data?

Tags: json, scala, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jackson

I am working with Scala and SpringBoot trying to consume an API Endpoint.

When requesting data via REST call, I receive a json in this format:

```js
[{"name":"John","lastName":"Appleseed"},[{"hobbie":"swimming"},{"hobbie":"language practitioning"}]]
```

As far as I know, this represents an Array of objects, but maybe I'm wrong.

Using Jackson, I have tried, for example:

**1st attempt:**

*Using `Seq[ Seq[ Hobbie ] ]`*

```java
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule( DefaultScalaModule )
  mapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false )
  
  logger.info( "\n\nInformation unmarshalling:" )
  case class Hobbie( @JsonProperty( value = "hobbie" ) hobbie: String )
  
  val informationJson = """ [{"name":"John","lastName":"Appleseed"},[{"hobbie":"swimming"},{"hobbie":"language practitioning"}]] """.trim
  val information = mapper.readValue[ Seq[ Seq[ Hobbie ] ] ]( informationJson )
  println( information )
```

, but I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `scala.collection.Seq<com.playground.Application$Hobbie>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"name":"John","lastName":"Appleseed"},[{"hobbie":"swimming"},{"hobbie":"language practitioning"}]]"; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.GenericFactoryDeserializerResolver$BuilderWrapper[0])
```

**2nd attempt:**

*Using `Seq[ Any ]`*

The data is read but it creates an ugly "default" data structure.

I have tried to figure out the best class to unmarshall the data but nothing seems to work properly.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Or use Scala idiomatic libs ...

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "Or use Scala idiomatic libs"?

Comment: Play-JSON, Circe, spray,...

Comment: I don't understand in which way your answer helps, but thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you is to write a transformation function that would map 'ugly "default" data structure' to the desired result.

If you want a production solution, you should write your own `Mapper` with a custom implementation that will produce the desired result.

A little hint on types about the result - if you have 2 types in an array on the same level of nesting - you can use `Either[FirstType, SecondType]`.

I don't know how jackson in scala works, but it might work out of the box if your result would be `Seq[Either[Person, Seq[Hobbie]]]`.